# Understanding VR ecology

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, oculus, virtual-reality

I have background in android and have developed few apps of my own. Now I want to explore VR app development for android. Going through forums etc., first thing I understand is that I need to have basic infrastructure like unity 3d sdk, cardboard sdk, cardboard device etc. I am not able to understand roles these individual components play in overall bigger picture.

Like, why do I need unity 3d sdk if I have android sdk and cardboard sdk, and android studio as dev environment?

Then, if I plan to develop for something like Oculus then what all sdks and devices are needed, and which programming language I can work with?

Comment: Wrong place for this question

Comment: @GerardoZinno at least tell OP a "right place" for this question

Comment: @dabadaba all I know is that stack overflow is for code-related question and this question is not about code. All I could say is look on other StackExchange communities.

Comment: @GerardoZinno that's a better comment than harshly shutting OP off ;)

Comment: In its current state, I'm not sure whether there are any Stack Exchange sites where this question would not be closed for one reason or another. Try to sift through the documentation for the answers first - oftentimes there'll be some sort of start-up guide that you can reference. Downloading a test project helps too, as it shows you all the pieces in place to get the technologies interacting. If, after this research and experimentation you run into an unsolvable problem, you can formulate that into a question here or perhaps http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/, depending on its specifics.

Comment: Thanks all for inputs. Yeah, I need to do lots of research it seems, which I have already started.Hope I would be able to do fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your options depend on which device you'll target:

- Game engines like Unity: You need Unity and some plug ins and of course the device you will target too:

> - Google Cardboard / Daydream
> - Samsung Gear VR

- From scratch application: Your language is java and you need to download the sdk for your target device:

> - Google Cardboard / Daydream SDK
> - Samsung Gear VR, Oculus Mobile SDK

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a lot of promise in web-based VR. Of course, the app will not be as high fidelity as a native application built in Unity or Java but you get the benefit of being able to target many platforms out of the box. ReactVR is a cool project coming out of facebook that is making it easier and more performant to build VR apps with web technologies.

Here is a cool starter-kit that can help you get started if you are interested: https://github.com/scaphold-io/react-vr-graphql

P.S. GraphQL is a great tool for enriching your VR apps with data no matter if you're building it with React, Unity, or Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out A-Frame (https://aframe.io), a web framework for building VR experiences. It's been out over a year and has a strong community and ecosystem. With web-based VR, you get cross-platform support across Rift, Vive, Cardboard, Daydream, GearVR out of the box. With A-Frame, you get all of the boilerplate with a single line of HTML. You just have to grab a VR-enabled browser.

A-Frame's architecture is similar to Unity's, entity-component, but A-Frame makes it declarative and similar to web development. With effort, the fidelity can rival native (https://blog.mozvr.com/a-painter/).